# Filter results by timestamp for the past 24 hours

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to filter the count of Rows found, per hour, over the past 24 hours.

I am using the following SQL query and 'landtime' is a DateTime field.

```
SELECT HOUR(landtime) as hour, COUNT(*) as total FROM ord_log WHERE landtime > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) GROUP BY HOUR(landtime) ORDER BY HOUR(landtime)
```

Sample data set > http://pastebin.com/0rYBnePG

The results looked as expected, until I looked at the data it was using.

It was pulling dates from days/weeks before todays date when I only want a count for the past 24 hours.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: That query should work as is, I think something else might be wrong. Please post some sample data from `ord_log`, the query results you are expecting, and the query results you are getting. Thanks!

Comment: Please see comment added to Ryans reply.

Comment: I added your sample data to a database and ran the query you proposed. It worked fine. It only looked at rows for the past 24 hours.

Comment: From my perspective, this works fine. Please see my request in the first comment. Please posts the query results you are expecting for a given set of sample data, and the query results you are getting instead.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No need to use a function, just use simple math:

```
SELECT HOUR(landtime) as hour, COUNT(*) as total FROM ord_log WHERE landtime > (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 1 DAY) GROUP BY HOUR(landtime) ORDER BY HOUR(landtime)
```

Comment: Thanks for that Ryan, looks simpler but still not provuding what I would expect. Please see the added dataset in my original question. I would expect it to return for instance 156 for Hour 05 on the 7th.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE day(data) = EXTRACT(day FROM (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 day))
```